# Expanding Values for a function Question

Tags: functions

Let $o_n$ be defined as follows:
$$o_1=1$$ $$o_2=3$$ $$o_3=5$$ 
As you can see, this function gives  **odd numbers**  the rule is $$o_n=2n-1$$

> Can this definition be used to find $o_{\frac{1}{2}}$ ?
>   The domain of this function is for all $n$ when $n \in \mathbb{Z} $ and I want it to be for all $n$ when $\mathbb{R} $ or $n \in  \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: To define a function properly you must specify the domain and codomain.  Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: Remeber that n is an integer number, then $o_{\frac{1}{2}}$ doesn't have sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't well-defined, for two reasons.

One problem is that finite sequences don't uniquely determine infinite sequences. Given a few values $o_1,o_2,o_3$, you can *guess* at what the rest of the values $o_n$ might be, and you can come up with formulas that fit the bill - but other people can guess differently and come up with different formulas that *also* fit the bill. For example, in the sequence $1,3,5,\dots$,

- There's a good reason why the next term might be $7$, as you explained.
- The next term might also be $10$: it might be [this](https://oeis.org/A092269) sequence.
- The next term might be $1$: it might be [this](https://oeis.org/A196020) sequence.
- The next term might be $13$: we might have $o_n = n^3 - 6n^2 + 13n - 7$.

The other problem is that, even if you have a well-defined function on the integers, say $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{R}$, $f(n) = 2n-1$, its extension to larger domains isn't well defined either. For example, suppose we try to extend it to $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$:

- We can just take $\tilde{f}(x) = 2x-1$. That works. Or...
- We can take $\tilde{f}(x) = 2x-1$ when $x$ is an integer, and $\tilde{f}(x) = \pi^2$ otherwise. Or...
- We can take $\tilde{f}(x) = 2x - 1 + \sin(2\pi x)$.
- etc. etc.

For each one of these, you can find $\tilde{f}(\frac{1}{2})$. But they may all be different depending on which $\tilde{f}$ you choose.